# Get max value for each different cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help on finding the maximum correlation value for each of the values placed in `column A` and `column B` and then paste the max value in `column V:X` as desired result.

I am trying to find out the max correlated pairs for each items from `column A`, as we can see in the image `"Apple"` is highly correlated with `"Vodafone"` similarly `"BMW"` is highly correlated with `"AUDI"` with 80% correlation. I need this to be pasted as final result in `column V:X`.

Can i simply use this snippet?

```vb
= WorksheetFunction.Max(A1,A2,A3 ,,,n)
```

[image]

```
Sub findbestcorrel()

Dim lrow As Long
Dim crow As Long
Dim sName As String


sName = "temp"
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = sName
lrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lrow).Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
crow = Worksheets("temp").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("temp").Range("A1:A" & crow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1


Worksheets(sName).Delete

End
```

i have reached so far got stuck at the next step where i need to take each of the cell value (columnA) from "temp" sheet and use autofilter to search for max value for each category in sheet1

Comment: Please shows us what have you tried so far and what problems you encountered.

Comment: Not sure who closed this, but i have shared but i tried so far

Comment: This has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array formula:

```
X1 = MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$8=V1)*($B$1:$B$8=W1),$D$1:$D$8;0))
```

Accept that formula using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`, then fill it down.

In VBA:

```
Sheet("NameOfSheet").Range("X1").FormulaArray = "_above_formula_"
```

That's all!

For further details, please see:

[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

[Range.FormulaArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray)

Comment: Hi Maciej thanks for sharing but i am not in favour of putting anything in cell V1 and W1, only the max  value from column A,B and D should get copied to column V,W and X . also, the data is dynamic

Comment: Sorry, i don't get you. Please, clarify what you want to achieve. I guess that you want to copy 3 rows with the highest value from A:D range into V:X range . Am i right? If yes, then you need to find 3 max values firstly then to copy them.

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: So, what have you done so far? What's the problem with your code?

Comment: i was looking for a vba program that will look out for cell value in column A and see the max correlation value against it in column D for eg 

Apple VOdafone 90%
Apple IDea 48%
Apple Hutch 56%
 so in this apple is best fit with vodafone with 90% value so this should get copied to cell V1, W1 and X1
now the code should move down further in column A only and check the below combination
Verizon Google 45%
Verizon AT&T 98% as we can see verizon is good with AT&T with 98% so this should get appended to cell V2,W2 and X2 and so on

Comment: Not sure who closed this, but i have shared but i tried so far